# Angular ngRoute factory design pattern

Tags: angularjs

I am hoping you can help me figure out if the design pattern that I am trying to use is 'good' or 'efficient' (in terms of best practice or lines of code etc.)

I have a page, which contains a list, then 2 more pages, for viewing individual items and for editing items. I am using ngRoute which allows me to very efficiently bounce the user between the pages.

However, this approach generates a lot of requests unless I can find a way to share data between controllers. Therefore, I have been using a factory to store the data and functions, however, I am concerned that my code is verbose and is doing more then I need it to.

I have stripped out some of the code so simplify the example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource','ngRoute'] );     
app.config([
        '$routeProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $window) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
            .when('/list/:id/edit', {
                templateUrl: '/html-client/view.html',
                controller: 'c_list'
            })
            .when('/list', {
                templateUrl: '/html-client/edit.html',
                controller: 'c_edit'
            })

        }
    ])
    .factory('f_list', function($http, $q) {
        var data = []
        var get_id = function(id){
            // code to check if the data is present and decide if to make the Ajax call or not.
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/list/'+id)
                    .then(function(resp) {
                        deferred.resolve(resp.data);
                    });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        var get = function () {
        // code to check if the data is present and decide if to make the Ajax call or not.
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/list')
                .then(function(resp) {
                    deferred.resolve(resp.data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        return {
            data:data,
            get:get,
            get_id:get_id,
        }
    })
    .controller('c_list',function ($scope,$route,f_list) {
        $scope.get = function(){
            f_list
            .get()
            .then(
                function(data) {
                    f_list.data = data;
                    $scope.list= f_list.data
                }
            );
        }
        f_list.data()
    })
    .controller('c_edit',function ($scope,$route,$routeParams,f_list) {
        var id = $routeParams.id
        $scope.get_id = function(){
            f_Projects.get_id (id).then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.list = data
                }
            );
        }
        $scope.get_id
    })
```

*(I haven't actually used terms like get and id in my actual code)*

**Questions:**

1. I understand the need for the factory to return promises, but is this the most efficient way of doing it?
2. Could I use $resource instead/combination with my factory?

Comment: You could use `requireJS`, as it's often done, to dynamically include controllers and template

Comment: I'm not sure how requireJS helps in this situation?